# Replace one image with another after clicking a button

Tags: android, android-image

I have defined an image in my xml file (imageview). I'd like to change it to another image after clicking a button in my activity. How can I do that?

Comment: it's generally considered good form to "accept" an answer if it solves your problem. You can do this by clicking the "tick" next to the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

First you `implements OnClickListener` interface to your activity class.
**Java Code**

```
    package it.codegen.tbx.my;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MytestdroidActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    Button b1;
    ImageView iw;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       b1.setOnClickListener(this); 

       iw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == b1)
        {
            iw.setImageResource(R.drawable.camara);
        }

    }
}
```

**XML file**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/icon"
        />
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

you should have 2 images in your drawable folder call icon and camara

Comment: hello...suppose im performing this one activity.user click to glow image... what if user goes from one activity to another and again coming back to activity one will the button remain as glow?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
image1.setImageResource ( R.drawable.another);
}
```

Comment: How to getback the original image on next click?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic thing that you are supposed to learn by doing tutorials and reading the getting started docs. Here's a sample:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_drawable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
final Button switchButoon = new Button(mContext);
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

switchButoon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I'd used ToggleButton and assign custom selector as a background:

```
<ToggleButton android:background="@drawable/custom_selector>
```

To avoid modification of the source use a selector, that you can place inside drawable\custom_selector.xml directory i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty Simple to do,

// First I create a variable named **OldImage** of type ImageView, and link it to the Layout File's ImageView

```
 ImageView oldImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.oldImageFileName);
```

// Create An OnClickListener Method To Update The File Resouce On Click to **NewFileName**,

```
 oldImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                oldImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.newFileName);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Button click listener just set your image like

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can solve it

```
ImageView imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewX);
imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageView perse = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewX);
        perse.setImageResource(R.drawable.fondochange);
     }
});
```