# android onactivity result is not working in tabactivity?

Tags: android, web-services

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener ,IServerResponse {
private RelativeLayout _myprofileRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _profilepicRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _coverpicRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _passwordRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _picilikedRelativeLayout=null;
private ToggleButton _mypicsToggleButton=null;
private Button _backButton=null;
private String _email=null;
private String _password=null;
private String _name=null;
private RelativeLayout _sendinviteRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _findfriendsRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _searchtagsRelativeLayout=null;
private RadioButton _maleRadioButton=null;
private RadioButton _femaleRadioButton=null;
private RadioButton _bothRadioButton=null;
private RadioButton _userRadioButton=null;
private RadioButton _brandRadioButton=null;
private RadioButton _retailerRadioButton=null;
private RelativeLayout _sharesettingRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _notificationRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _supportRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _logoutRelativeLayout=null;
private RelativeLayout _aboutRelativeLayout=null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    _myprofileRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myprofile_layout);
    _profilepicRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.profilepic_layout);
    _coverpicRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.coverpic_layout);
    _passwordRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.password_layout);
    _picilikedRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.picliked_layout);

    _mypicsToggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.mypic_toggleButton);

    _sendinviteRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sendinvite_layout);
    _findfriendsRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.findfriends_layout);
    _searchtagsRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.searchtag_layout);

    _maleRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.male_checkbox);
    _femaleRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.female_checkbox);
    _bothRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.both_checkbox);
    _userRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.user_checkbox);
    _brandRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.brand_checkbox);
    _retailerRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.retailer_checkbox);

    _sharesettingRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sharesetting_layout);
    _notificationRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.notisetting_layout);
    _supportRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.supportsetting_layout);
    _aboutRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.aboutsetting_layout);
    _logoutRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.logoutsetting_layout);
    _backButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

    _myprofileRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _profilepicRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _coverpicRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _passwordRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _picilikedRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

    _sendinviteRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _findfriendsRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _searchtagsRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);

    _sharesettingRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _notificationRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _supportRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _aboutRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _logoutRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    _backButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity=(TabGroupActivity)getParent();
    Intent intent =null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.back_btn:
        this.finish();
        break;
    case R.id.myprofile_layout:
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditProfileActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("editprofile", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.password_layout:
        intent=new Intent(this, ChangePasswordActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("changepassword", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.profilepic_layout:
        chooseImageDialog("", "Choose profile pic ?", this.getParent(), false);

        break;
    case R.id.coverpic_layout:
        chooseImageDialog("", "Choose profile pic ?", this.getParent(), false);

        break;
    case R.id.picliked_layout:
        intent=new Intent(this, PicsILikedActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("pics", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.sendinvite_layout:
        break;
    case R.id.findfriends_layout:
        intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FindFriendsActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("findfriends", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.searchtag_layout:
        break;
    case R.id.sharesetting_layout:
        intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShareSettingSocialActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("sharesettings", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.notisetting_layout:
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationActivity.class);
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("notif", intent);
        break;
    case R.id.supportsetting_layout:
        break;
    case R.id.aboutsetting_layout:
        break;
    case R.id.logoutsetting_layout:
        TabGroupActivity tabgroupactivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
        tabgroupactivity.finish();

        intent=new Intent(this, LoginScreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
            String imagepath= getpath(chosenImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            getprofilepic();
            Constant._profilePicBase64=Constant.convertBitmapToBase64(bitmap);


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Unable to get Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            try{
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                Constant._profilePicBase64=Constant.convertBitmapToBase64(bitmap);

            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Unable to get Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}
private void getprofilepic() {
    if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(SettingsActivity.this)) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",Constant.USER_ID));
        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo",Constant._profilePicBase64));

        // CALL WEBSERVICE
        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().registerForServerResponse(
                (IServerResponse) SettingsActivity.this);
        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().callGetAppWebService(false,
                this, WSConstant.getUrl(WSConstant.METHOD_CHANGE_PROFILE_PHOTO),
                SettingsActivity.this, WSConstant.PID_CHANGE_PROFILE_PHOTO, false,
                requestParaList);
    }
}

private String getpath(Uri chosenImageUri) {
    String[] projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor=managedQuery(chosenImageUri, projection,null,null,null);
    int column=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column);
}
public void chooseImageDialog(final String title, String message,
        final Context context, final boolean redirectToPreviousScreen) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intentfile = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intentfile, 2);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(Constant.choosePhotoBitmap!=null){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.obj = response;
    msg.arg1 = processid;
    _handler.sendMessage(msg);      
}
private Handler _handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.arg1) {
        case WSConstant.PID_CHANGE_PROFILE_PHOTO:
            getJsonResponse(msg.obj.toString());
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    private void getJsonResponse(String response) {
        JSONObject json=null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                String message= jsonObject.getString("status");
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Constant.showAlertDialog("status","YES",SettingsActivity.this.getParent(),false);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ProfileScreenActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
                    Constant.showAlertDialog("status","NO",SettingsActivity.this.getParent(),false);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
}
```

i am using webservice for changing my profile picture ,i have used tabactivity with onactivityresult.,but the problem is that data is not going in onactivity result.,when i debug my code.,what i do.,please help me.

Comment: Please explain your scenario properly. What you want to do? select Image from gallery and upload that image on server. Right ?

Comment: Try Referring to [this][1] link.
See answer of miuranga.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024881/replace-one-image-with-another-after-clicking-a-button

Comment: @nilkash sir i am using webservice in setting screen,where i want to change my profie pic ,from server,when i click on camera..,i take picture.,and i want that this image sholud be replace by my profile picture.,i have tried this,but my response is always no.,and image is not changing.

Comment: @HarshGoswami thnku sir.., i try.....:)

Comment: @HarshGoswami but it is not related to webservice.,it is static.

Comment: @nilkash sir did you get any solution????...please help me..,i am trubbling from this problem since 2 days..:(